# HTTP Status 405-Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: http

When I type this into the URL, http://localhost:8080/sharing-api/application/submit --> the method in the restController in api works

When I put the same link in action of my html form,

```
<form th:object="${sharingForm}" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/sharing-api/application/submit" >
```

it gives HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed,
Request method 'POST' not supported
The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.

Please help!

Comment: When you type or copypaste URL in browser it will perform HTTP GET, not HTTP POST. Check your method in REST controller, it should be configured for POST

Comment: It depends on framework that you use to handle form data. If it is SpringMVC please refer to manual https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Comment: Thank you so much! It works when I configured to POST in my REST controller.

Comment: @Learner can you share your REST Controller code on how you have configured to POST?